# How to use \L DOS command for creating Log file in SSIS

Tags: logging, command-line, ssis, dos, package

I'm trying to use the below command to execute for generating the log file for SSIS package.

DTExec /FILE "C:\Documents and Settings\CP0808\My Documents\Test.dtsx"   /logger "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;c:\log.txt"

But it got the error as below. Please advise.

Started:  12:03:20 AM
Error: 2009-05-04 12:03:21.15
   Code: 0xC001000E
   Source: Test
   Description: The connection "c:\log.txt" is not found. This error is thrown b
y Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
End Error
Error: 2009-05-04 12:03:21.18
   Code: 0xC001000E
   Source: Test
   Description: The connection "c:\log.txt" is not found. This error is thrown b
y Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
End Error
Error: 2009-05-04 12:03:21.21
   Code: 0xC02020EA
   Source: Test Log provider "{1AEAB490-1124-4A84-981F-7C1FDD80A721}"
   Description: The connection manager "c:\log.txt" is not found. A component fa
iled to find the connection manager in the Connections collection.
End Error

Please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the logging inside of BIDS. It will show you that you need to set up a connection manager, and that where you wrote "C:\log.txt", you're meant to have the name of the connection manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot John...
I was fighting wth this error for 4 days...
Noe it is working fine...